# Flask-Login: user_callback function resets to None after login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

This may look like a long complicated question, But I'm guessing this is not. It may probably have got something to do with the way I used flask-login. Since I'm new to flask and flask-login, I cant figure it out. I've been stuck on this for a day now.

I am getting the error: cannot call NoneType in my flask application. The strangest thing is that somehow the user_callback function gets set to None after the login.

I have the following urls set inside my flask app

/admin/login - Admin Login URL

```
@application.route(base_url + '/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def admin_login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        if request.form['username'] == "root" and request.form['password'] == os.environ['ROOT_PASS']:
            user = User("root", 1)
            login_user(user)
            return "OK! Logged In!"
        else:
            return render_template('admin_login.html', error="Invalid username or password", form=form)
    return render_template('admin_login.html', form=form)
```

And

/test - A restricted URL with the following view function

```
@application.route('/test')
@login_required(1)
def test():
    return "hello"
```

Before logging in everything seems to work fine. If I go to /test I get an unauthorized error as it is supposed to work. And also if I go to /admin/login I get the login template.

But after logging in, I can't go to /test or /admin/login. I am getting cannot call NoneType error. Here's the complete traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/lib/helpers/login.py", line 14, in decorated_view
    if not current_user.is_authenticated():
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 796, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 364, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/Users/harry/Sites/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 326, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

And it looks like the user_callback function has been set as None.

But I have actually added the user_loader function. Like this.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    # Check if user is root
    if userid == "root":
        return User(userid, 1)
    else:
        return None
```

Here's the modified login_required function:

```
# login_required function
# This is an improvement over flask-login's login_required
# This implementation supports clearance levels
# A route can be accessed by anyone having a clearance level less than the 
# set clearance level
def login_required(clearance="100"):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.is_authenticated():
               return login_manager.unauthorized()
            u_clearance = login_manager.reload_user().get_clearance()
            if (u_clearance > clearance):
                return login_manager.unauthorized()      
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

On your test method, remove the `1` in the [`login_required`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_required) decorator:

```
@application.route('/test')
@login_required
def test():
    return "hello"
```

Comment: I have used @login_required(1) because I'm using a custom decorator to add user roles to login. 1 signifies the admin role.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! It looks like I've been reinitializing login_manager from some other part of the code!
Now i've resolved this bug.
Sorry for the inconvenience caused.